# Ideal technology stack for Drupal 6 in Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, php5, drupal, windows-sbs

My background is predominantly Linux-based servers, with which I can configure anything however I want. However, I'm building a Drupal6 site for a client, who (despite my warnings) wishes to self-host from a server in his offices -- and is running Windows Server 2008R2 (likely upgrading to Small Business Server 2011 at some point).

While I have a good idea of the technology stack I'd use in Linux, I'm much less sure how I'd go about this in a Windows-based server environment.

**What is the ideal technology stack for serving web-based PHP applications (specifically Drupal) in Windows?**

And no, I can't reformat the thing as a Linux box. :) Thanks!

**EDIT:** One thing worth noting is that I've used MAMP (Apache2, MySQL) in Mac OS 10.6 as my testing environment. It'd be great if the tech stack could use MySQL as I'd ideally like to just dump then import the tables I've been using.

Comment: Not really an answer cuz I don't know what's ideal on Windows... But have you seen this? http://drupal.org/node/1130898 The stack includes IIS and SQL Server Express.

Comment: @Jason -- That's helpful, but seems more directed towards Drupal7. Microsoft Web PI also supports Acquia Drupal 6, but I don't know how the Acquia install profile differs from standard Drupal and am thus a little hesitant to use that.

Comment: The post at http://lab.usgin.org/groups/drupal-development/running-drupal-windows-server-2008-machine worries about running PHP on IIS. This is kind of the concern I'm having. Windows Server admins -- what's the deal with PHP and IIS? Is it at all stable?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal tech stack on Windows for Drupal is 100% without a doubt Apache + PHP + MySQL. This software now sees more downloads for Windows then it does for Linux (since about 2009).

You should try any number of WAMP (Windows, Apache, MySQL, PHP) packages.

I think you will find [WampDeveloper Pro](http://www.devside.net/server/webdeveloper) ideal for your situation. It has a full user-interface that adds and manages websites, it installs web applications such as Drupal 6.2 for you automatically, manages local DNS, keeps Apache + MySQL + PHP updated at all times, and makes things very easy. But you pay for it (well worth it).

Though if you're client (or you) are looking for a free WAMP stack, there is [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) and [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). But they don't have any of the features that WampDeveloper does, and have no official support.

Comment: That's helpful; I may go with WampDeveloper Pro.